# Class name is not defined in the module unless it's used in the code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have created some classes in a module, f.i. Request (app/models/api/request.rb)

```
class Api::Request
end
```

And now I want to check in the console does the class exist?

```
>> Api.const_defined?('Request')
=> false
>> Api::Request
=> Api::Request
>> Api.const_defined?('Request')
=> true
```

Strange, but the script cannot see the class name unless I use it in the code.
How to fix this? And if you can explain the issue, it will be great.
The project uses Rails 2.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is with the rails autoload mechanism. Basically what it does is to react to the method const_missing which you can define on every object. When this method is called, Rails looks for a file which is likely to contain a definition for the missing constant and requires it. The problem is that

```
Api::Request
```

triggers const_missing but

```
Api.const_defined?('Request')
```

does not.

You can write your own const_defined? like this (the code would go into a rails initializer):

```
def Module.autoload_const_defined?(name)
  self.const_get name
ensure
  return self.const_defined?(name)
end
```

which first tries to autoload the constant.

Comment: Thank you for so detailed answer! I will use your function

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming upon this in future - it's much better style to do something like the following:

```
def Module.autoload_const_defined?(name)
  const_get(name)
rescue NameError => e
  const_defined?(name)
end
```

`return` inside an `ensure` block means that any exceptions that occur are silently thrown away, and have the potential to make debugging really tricky.